# Text file read offset is not consistent with the block defined by seek and tell in python

Tags: python, seek

I want to read a large text file block by block define by offsets. Before that, I used `file.tell` to define the start position of each block by quick screening the file with `file.seek(0)`, i.e., from start of the file. Then each block is defined by the size using `size = i1 - i0`, where `i0`, `i1` are start positions of current and next block. The block is easy to be obtained by `file.read(size)` for further processing. The problem is that block defined in this way is not consistent with what is actually presented in the file. That is, there are additional texts obtained other than the block I want to get. Here is a simple example by supposing each block is a single line.

```
>>> # construct a simple text file
>>> texts = [f"This is line No. {i}\n" for i in range(20)]
>>> with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(texts)

>>> with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.read())

This is line No. 0
This is line No. 1
This is line No. 2
This is line No. 3
This is line No. 4
This is line No. 5
This is line No. 6
This is line No. 7
This is line No. 8
This is line No. 9
This is line No. 10
This is line No. 11
This is line No. 12
This is line No. 13
This is line No. 14
This is line No. 15
This is line No. 16
This is line No. 17
This is line No. 18
This is line No. 19

>>> # Get offset for each line
>>> offsets = []
>>> with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
        b = f.seek(0)
        for line in iter(f.readline, ""):
            offsets.append(b)
            # start position of next block
            b = f.tell()

>>> offsets
[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 221, 242, 263, 284, 305, 326, 347, 368, 389]
>>> # Read blocks by offsets
>>> for i0, i1 in zip(offsets[:-1], offsets[1:]):
        _ = f.seek(i0, 0)
        text = f.read(i1 - i0)
        print(f"## Start = {i0}, end = {i1}, offset = {i1-i0}")
        print("Block text: ")
        print(text)

## Start = 0, end = 20, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 0
T
## Start = 20, end = 40, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 1
T
## Start = 40, end = 60, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 2
T
## Start = 60, end = 80, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 3
T
## Start = 80, end = 100, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 4
T
## Start = 100, end = 120, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 5
T
## Start = 120, end = 140, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 6
T
## Start = 140, end = 160, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 7
T
## Start = 160, end = 180, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 8
T
## Start = 180, end = 200, offset = 20
Block text: 
This is line No. 9
T
## Start = 200, end = 221, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 10
T
## Start = 221, end = 242, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 11
T
## Start = 242, end = 263, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 12
T
## Start = 263, end = 284, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 13
T
## Start = 284, end = 305, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 14
T
## Start = 305, end = 326, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 15
T
## Start = 326, end = 347, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 16
T
## Start = 347, end = 368, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 17
T
## Start = 368, end = 389, offset = 21
Block text: 
This is line No. 18
T
```

Seems `f.tell()` tells the right start position of each block, but when I want to get blocks by the sizes defined by position differences of `offsets`, more texts were obtained. Why and how can I fix this?

**===========Update===========**

When I used `rb` to read the texts in binary mode, the same results obtained. This is not because of read mode.

```
with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
b = f.seek(0)
for line in iter(f.readline, b""):
    offsets.append(b)
    # start position of next block
    b = f.tell()
>>> offsets
[0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 221, 242, 263, 284, 305, 326, 347, 368, 389]
```

Comment: On a file opened in text mode, the values returned by `.tell()` have *no valid usage* other than to be passed to `.seek()` later - performing any sort of math on the values is meaningless.  This was originally to support historical systems that don't actually have byte-oriented files at all, additional bits had to be tacked on to the file position to specify a byte offset within the words actually stored in the file.  But it still applies to one modern system - on Windows, newlines are 2 bytes on disk vs. 1 character in memory, causing a discrepancy in positions.

Comment: @jasonharper I think that's worth writing up as an answer.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks. I realized this once I searched online. But based on others' answers, I used `rb` in stead of opening file in `r` mode to make the reading in binary mode, I found I can't easily get the offset if I want to still go through the file line by line. Would appreciate if you can post an answer and fix all these, as Karl suggested.

Comment: Agree with @jsonsharper. When a file is opened in r mode, then it is treated as text mode where in new line is treated as single character. If you want it to be treated as 2 character. you must read file in binary mode